# Android playing live radio stream?

Tags: android

Can anyone please suggest me how to play live radio stream url in android. Someone who has experience in playing live radio url in android.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
 try
   {
        MediaPlayer media = new MediaPlayer();
        media.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE);
        media.setDataSource("http://indiespectrum.com:9000");
        media.prepare();
        media.start();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Getting Exception
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void startRadio(String streamUrl) {
       MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
       mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(
            new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error in MediaPlayer: (" + what +") with extra (" +extra +")" );
                }
            });

    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(streamUrl); 
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "IllegalArgumentException");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "IllegalStateException");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "IOException");
    }
}
```

Quick copy paste ..

Comment: Are you sure this it will work? I have tried this on samsung phones and it always throw prepare called in wrong state exception. Do you know any other method that work on all phone for playing live radio url.

Comment: Yes I'm sure .. I use that code in an application called "Twizz", that plays music on all devices I've tested with .. Just tried it right now on my Samsung SGS2.

I do have some other checks and more sensible logging .. but that's basically it.
 
Maybe, try with another URL?  (Make sure you don't call MediaPlayer.create() with my code)

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work ! It gave me `IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000`. Any ideas?